# C: create array from char*

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I am using an arduino to receive RF messages from an RF69 chip.
The message contains weather data, like temperature, humidity and barometric pressure.
The string received looks like this: 1:22.26:41.53:1023.73 (msg type:temp:hum:pres)
I need to convert this to an array, then copy the data into float values.
Using strtok i am able to copy some data, but i seem to be missing values.

```
Serial.print("Message: "); 
Serial.println((char*)buf); //Message: 1:22.32:41.39:1023.77

char* data;
data = (char*)buf; //incoming from radio buffer
char separator[] = ":"; //delimeter
char *array[3]; //expect 3 value
int i=0; //start loop at 0
array[i] = strtok(data,separator); //first token
while(array[i]!=NULL) {
    array[++i] = strtok(NULL,separator);
    Serial.println(array[i]);
}
```

This seems to output correctly:

```
Message: 1:22.32:41.18:1023.77
22.32
41.18
1023.77
```

When i then assign the floats, i am missing the t value:

```
float t = atof(array[1]);
float h = atof(array[2]);
float p = atof(array[3]);
Serial.print("Temperature =  "); Serial.println(t);
Serial.print("Rel. Humidity =  "); Serial.println(h);
Serial.print("Pressure =  "); Serial.println(p);
```

Output:

```
Temperature =  0.00
Rel. Humidity =  41.33
Pressure =  1023.78
```

Can someone explain why i am missing the temperature value?
Also since i am not experienced with C, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `char *array[3]; //expect 3 value`. You actually have 4 values not 3. See: `atof(array[3])`, that's the 4th value in the array. Writing/reading that value results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: I changed *array[3] to 4, but behavior is the same,  missing the temperature float.

Comment: @HyperDevil - that is because your loop writes NULL to `array[4]` - you test for `strtok()` returning NULL _after_ you have already assigned that NULL to `array[i]` when `i == 4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
while( array[i] != NULL){ 
    array[++i] = strtok(NULL,separator);
    Serial.println(array[i]);
}
```

writes to `array[3]` and `array[4]` which are out of bounds. The presure field is written to `array[0]`, then NULL is written to `array[4]`.

Change to:

```
while( i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array) &&
       array[i] != NULL) 
{
    array[i] = strtok(NULL,separator);
    Serial.println(array[i]);
    i++ ;
}
```

which overwrites the pointer at `array[0]` that has the message type that you are discarding and iterates until all fields are extracted rather then when `strtok()` return NULL.

Then change the indexes in the `atof()`:

```
float t = atof(array[0]);
float h = atof(array[1]);
float p = atof(array[2]);
```

You might also verify the the message type is correct.

```
array[i] = strtok(data,separator); //first token
if( array[i][0] == '1' && array[i][1] == 0 )
{
    while( i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array) &&
           array[i] != NULL) 
    {
        array[i] = strtok(NULL,separator);
        Serial.println(array[i]);
        i++ ;
    }
}
```

If in fact you wanted to keep the message type, then `array` requires 4 elements and the loop body will become:

```
        i++ ;
        array[i] = strtok(NULL,separator);
        Serial.println(array[i]);
```

You could pre-increment in `array[++i]` as per your original code, but I would not recommend it - it does not serve clarity and the semantics and sequencing become complicated when used in more complex expressions - always used it "stand-alone" to avoid errors and misunderstanding.

Comment: hi, i seem to get this error on compiling your example: lvalue required as left operand of assignment, on the if statement? == instead of =  on the right operator?

Comment: "prints an array element array[i] that has not yet been initialised". I can't see how that is true. `++i` increments the index and then uses it. So in the first loop the index is 1 after the pre-increment, it stores a value into `array[1]` and prints `aray[1]`.

Comment: changing = to == on the right comparison seems to make it compile now. and the missing t float is now filled. thanks!

Comment: @HyperDevil - yes it was a typo.  You are right about the print - that explains why the output was correct.  Too little sleep!